# Function composition $f(g(x)) = x$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f: N \rightarrow N_0$, where $f(x) = x-1$; and $g: N \rightarrow N_1$, where $g(x) = x+1$;

$$(f \circ g)(x) = x?$$

Can anyone explain why/if this is true? Shouldn't it be $x^2$?

Comment: What's *N0,N1*?${}{}$

Comment: Set of nat. numbers starting from 0 and from 1

Comment: The notation $f(g(x))(x)$ is not completely clear. I think what is meant is $(f \circ g)(x) = f(g(x))$.

Comment: you're right; I wasn't clear on what the (x) was standing for. As someone wrote below I assumed its f(g(x)) * x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be $f(g(x))=f(x+1)=x+1-1=x$

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way (the notation might not be $100\%$ but it works)

$ f( g(x) ) = g(x) - 1 = (x+1) - 1  = x$